# Can't select row with condition against nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblactivity
(
  action NVARCHAR(300)
);
```

However when I run the following query, I get no results:

```
select * from tblactivity where action like 'រៀន%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Unicode strings for conditions with non Latin languages like that

```
select * from tblactivity where action like N'រៀន%'
```

Of course you would need to change `រៀន` to the actual word in your language becuse it was probably rendered incorrectly.